# Does putting a command in single quotes have any effect in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

I've stumbled upon a script where the author puts every external command (that is not a builtin or function) in single quotes. As I have never seen that coding style before, I'm wondering, it there any difference between the following two examples:

`'cat' $myfile`

vs.

`cat $myfile`

Please ignore the fact that the author chose not to quote the variable holding the file name. I would definitely put that in double quotes and I'm aware of the effect of quotes around the variable. I'm merely interested in whether the quotes around the command have any effect. Both examples work fine, but it is my understanding that the single quotes are superfluous here. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only seen quotes used in shell scripts for commands that have a space in the path, which often happens using Bash in Win10. Maybe its a habit the author picked up. But it is superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, quoting a string that has no whitespaces or special characters is strictly equivalent to not quoting at all.

However, there are a few cases where quoting makes a difference.

### Preventing alias

Many linux distributions automatically setup aliases for programs like `ls` or `grep`, e.g.:

```sh
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

If you call the quoted command, the alias will not be expanded:

```sh
ls / # shows the root files and folders with colors
'ls' / # shows the root files and folders without any color
```

The alias is not used even if the command is partly quoted:

`'l's / # shows the root files and folders without any color`

(I would strongly advise against doing that, though)

### Reserved keywords

Some keywords must not be quoted. For instance this will work:

`time cat $myfile`

But this will fail:

`'time' cat $myfile`

> -bash: time: command not found

### Tilde expansion

The tilde character `~` may be used to reach the home directory. Alone, it points to the home directory of the current user:

`ls ~`

When followed directly by a username, it points to the home directory of that user:

`ls ~root`

When quoting the tilde character, the directory is not expanded and the shell tries look for a file containing the tilde character instead:

`ls '~'`

> ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory

### Tests

The `[[ ]]` operator can make use of `test` commands, such as `-f`, `-e`, etc. However the directive must not be quoted.

`[[ -e /tmp ]] && echo /tmp exists || echo /tmp is missing`

> /tmp exists

`[[ '-e' /tmp ]] && echo /tmp exists || echo /tmp is missing`

> -bash: conditional binary operator expected
>
> -bash: syntax error near `/tmp'

### Conclusion

There are many cases where quoting does make a difference. I think the first situation is the reason why your author wrote the code.

PS. this list is not exhaustive, I especially omitted cases like whitespaces, asterisks, pipes, ampersands, etc. because I assume you already know why someone would want to quote them.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. user1934428 already covered the alias case and as you said as well, that's probably the reason why the author chose to do so. The commands in question are all basic unix/GNU tools such as cat, date, mkdir, etc. So, the other examples you listed don't apply here.

Comment: @Timo the reserved keyword may apply to your case if the author quoted keywords, e.g. if for some reason he wanted to implement his own `time` or `read` program, then quoting those calls would ensure that his implementations are called instead of the builtin commands.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has an effect, though mostly for a really arcane reason:

Consider this weird construct

```
alias cat='echo x'
cat foo # would output x foo
'cat' foo # Would output the content of the file foo
```

Putting it inside quotes causes bash not to run the alias. One could have achieved this effect also with

```
command cat foo # Also outputs the file foo
```

The difference is that putting the command in quotes only skips alias definitions, while using `command` would also skip a function definition. Since aliases are usually not enabled in scripts, using the quotes are rarely of use.

Comment: Thanks! That explains all.(Well, aside from the question why the author cares about such a corner case but not quoting variables derived from possibly less trustworthy user input... But I didn't ask that one, so ;))